# Multiplying 2 equations together

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x+y=i$ and $a+b=i$ is the equation $(x+y)(a+b)=(i)(i)$ always valid/true?

Example.
Let $x = 1, y=2, a=2, b=1, i=3$
\begin{equation}
1+2=3 \\2+1=3 \\(3)(3)=(3)(3)
\end{equation}

Is there any edge cases where and equation = the same thing multiplied together be false?

Comment: Isn't it trivially true?

Comment: Think about your proposition: *the same thing multiplied together be false* – does that make any sense? Is it possible for $ab \neq ab \forall a, b \in \Bbb R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following always holds

$$(x+y)(a+b)=ii=i(x+y)=i(a+b)$$